# Splitting hourly time series in R

Tags: r, split, time-series

I'm trying to split a time series dataset into train and test set with R.

The dataset structure is the following:

```
Date (format = %Y-%m-%d)     | Hour (24 H format) |       Value

         2018-09-23                    15                 12345
```

I have transformed this dataset in a times series format using this code :

```
tt <- ts(df$Value,start=c(2018,09,00:00),frequency=24*365)
```

After this I tried to split the series in a training and test set using this code:

```
y_train <- window(tt, c(2018,09), c(2020,05)

y_test <- window(tt, c(2020,06))
```

But the test set contains only two observation (instead of 1488 values).

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How did you get `tt` in your `window`?

Comment: Sorry for the typo, now i have corrected my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example, for nrow(df) = 200

```
tt <- ts(df$Value, frequency = 24, start = 1)        

y_train <- ts(tt[1:140], frequency=24) #70%
y_test <- ts(tt[141:200], frequency=24) #30%
```